# How to change the web app's database from RDB to Hadoop when using JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

If you use DAO as an interface between the application and the database, you can change the database from RDB to Hadoop (which has totally different table schema) without making any modification to the application side. (all you need to do is to change DAO.) If you use JPA, is it also easy to change the database? Can you change the database without making any modification on the application?
If yes, could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Theoretically, you can do it by changing the `persistence.xml` file. Very often, though, it will not work

Answer (score 0):

**JPA is only for RDBMS (Relational Database Management System)** so yes you change change between Oracle, MSSQL, MySQL, PostreSQL etc BUT you cannot change to a NoSQL database like Hadoop or MongoDB.

To change it you have to use the Database JDBC Driver and set the Hibernate dialect (or whatever JPA implementation you use) accordingly.